# The usage of 'know' with object and object complement

Tags: verbs

Designers draw on their experience of design when approaching
a new project.

This includes the use of previous designs **that they
know work** ― both designs that they have created themselves and
those that others have created.

Is this something like know A B (like "I know him(A) a doctor(B)" ?

Comment: It would often be *...designs that they know **to** work*. See [this usage chart](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=that+we+know+to+exist%2Cthat+we+know+exist&year_start=1900&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=10) showing how we've increasingly started discarding the "infinitive marker" ***to*** in contexts like *[things] that we know **to** exist*. But we ***never*** discard that marker if the actual verb is [TO BE] - we'd always refer to, say, *the man that I know **to be** a doctor* (only the most uneducated yokel would use *...that I know **be** a doctor* there).

Answer (score 2):

No.

- **I know him a doctor.*

is ungrammatical. Not all verbs take part in this construction, 2-place with B-Raising (see [John Lawler's article](http://www-personal.umich.edu/%7Ejlawler/cliffs-equi-raising.pdf)). To illustrate:

[I consider **him**] [**He** is a friend]. The object of the first statement twins as the (suppressed) subject of the second statement: B-raising (... to subject). [I consider ***him*** a friend]. (The object of the second simple statement becomes an object complement in the process.)

Note that 'regard' doesn't have this property: an *as* is required.

As seen, one that does is *consider*

- *I consider him a friend*, a grammatical deletion of
- *I consider him to be a friend*.

But 'know' needs the 'to be', undeleted.

The basic structure you're asking about in your first example is a noun with a defining relative clause

- *designs that / which they know work.*

where the relativiser 'that' is often deleted, especially in conversation

- *designs they know work.*

Comment: The chances of the OP understanding Lawler's article are about as likely as Covid disappearing tomorrow.

Comment: ELU's mission statement is primarily to build up a searchable repository of sound English usage and analysis. Appropriate questions are a means to an end; the target audience is non-unitary.

Comment: The primary purpose of an answer is to respond to the OP's question with something useful that they can understand. In any case, no one talks today of B-raising or Equi.

Comment: No; ELU is aimed at an audience wider than one. Questions are often off-topic, but responses are often given in comments, to aid the questioner without encouraging mediocrity. // Have you noticed _I added a reference_? Feel free to add a more up-to-date analysis, provided you don't fail to do similarly (attributed and linked ... see the Help Center).

Comment: The OP comes first; anything else may be a useful side benefit for others. What is the point of giving the OP an answer that they are unlikely to understand? A reference is not going to resolve that. A good answer is accurate and crisply-phrased, and focused on the OP's specific question. That's what we should aspire to.

Comment: I guess I could understand pretty well "Lawler's article". Thanks for the reference link.

Comment: Edwin, I guess your last "designs they know work." is missing "to". I mean because "know" needs "to" according to your explanation. I believe my initial example is correct. If so, in this phrase "designs that they know work" 'they know' is an inserted phrase.

Comment: I don't see that. Do-support (for emphasis) is possible: 'This includes the use of previous designs that they know _do_ work' where no infinitive-marker ('to') could be inserted. 'I know/see/believe/think ... [that] they work.'

Comment: I've found this on internet:  I’ve never known it (to) snow in July before. This means 'to' can be inserted.

Comment: Conceded; 'designs [that] they know to work' _are_ grammatical with the 'know to V' verb phrase. But 'modifications [that] they hope / think / see work', where to-insertion is at best extremely doubtful, argue against a 'suppressed to' analysis (perhaps not historically). Note that 'designs that they hope work' has a very different modal status from 'designs that work', so parenthetical insertion is easily discounted in at least some examples.

Answer (score 0):

> This includes the use of previous designs that they know work ― both
> designs that they have created themselves and those that others have
> created.
>
> Is this something like know A B (like "I know him(A) a doctor(B)" ?

No. Perhaps the easiest way to explain it (I don't deal in abstruse grammatical theory) is as follows:

The basic structure of the sentence is:

*This includes the use of **previous designs that work**.*

We can now insert the parenthetical "we know"

*This includes the use of previous designs that (we know) work.*

That last form is simply a contraction of

*This includes the use of previous designs that, as we know, work.*

Comment: simple and useful for non-native speakers

Comment: From [EnglishClub.com](https://www.englishclub.com/grammar/sentence/parenthetical-expression.htm#:~:text=A%20parenthetical%20expression%20is%20a,sentence%20works%20just%20the%20same.): _A parenthetical expression is a word or words added to a sentence **without changing the meaning** or grammar of the original sentence._  [emphasis mine]  'They claim to have some designs that work. We're not sure about this claim.' This shows that 'designs that work' need not be the same set as 'designs that we know work'. This cannot be regarded as a parenthetical. Similarly for 'designs that we think work'.

Comment: @ Edwin Ashworth -  You say, *'They claim to have some designs that work. We're not sure about this claim.'*   Where did you get "claim" and "not sure" from. They are not in the original quote, or anywhere else I can find.